# How to install gem in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

How do you install plugins in Rails 4? Or more specifically, how do you install the Princely plugin for PrinceXML? I've spent a lot of time Googling but have not come up with anything. Everything seems to be for earlier versions of Rails. I get the impression that one would put in in the Gem file somehow? If someone could clarify this for me, I'd be most appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Gemfile

```
gem 'princely', '~> 1.4.1'
```

or if you prefer to point to github

```
gem 'princely', github: 'mbleigh/princely'
```

then run `bundle install`

Comment: So, it's treated just as if it were a gem? I got confused because I kept seeing it referred to as a plugin and somehow thought plugins and gems were managed differently because they were packaged differently.

Answer (score 0):

Go to into your gemfile, do what Antarr Byrd said. Basically put in those lines above or below and of the lines about gems already there. Running bundle install will result in a new Gemfile.lock, at which point it'll start working.